# When importing JSON file into Firebase, how to set initial key pair?

Tags: json, firebase

Ater importing JSON file into Firebase, it starts of the index at `0` (the top most zero) instead of `locations`.

[image: What ends up in Firebase]

This is the JSON file I'm importing

```
[{"locations":
    [{"location_id":1,"location":"2331 Fair","location_type_id":1},
    {"location_id":2,"location":"6800 Norm","location_type_id":1}]
}]
```

How can I get rid of the top `0` so that my reference starts with `[name-of-firebase-database]/locations` instead of `[name-of-firebase-database]/0/locations`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your JSON structure from:

```
[{"locations":
    [{"location_id":1,"location":"2331 Fair","location_type_id":1},
    {"location_id":2,"location":"6800 Norm","location_type_id":1}]
}]
```

to

```
{"locations":
    [{"location_id":1,"location":"2331 Fair","location_type_id":1},
    {"location_id":2,"location":"6800 Norm","location_type_id":1}]
}
```

The `0` is there because your top level structure is a list.